# Why even numbers of batteries?

Tags: batteries

Why do most household appliances (flashlights, wireless controllers, keyboards, etc.) use two or multiples of two batteries, side by side? The circuit could surely be complete with just a single battery, or three batteries, or five batteries, or whatever.

Why the even number of batteries?

Comment: This both falls under consumer electronics and falls under asking us to give random feedback on designs of other engineers without having their designs. I have closed as not constructive but off topic would be a valid reason also. I am sorry to be a bearer of bad news @jeremy, but this site is intended to focus on the design of electronics.

Comment: If we talk about a side-by-side design using a even number of batteries makes sense. Other than that the number of batteries is dictated by the voltage which is needed to operate a circuit.

Comment: with an even # of batteries oriented in oposite directions the connection points are on the same side and perhaps lower cost to build.

Answer (score 2):

No real reason, just coincidence.  I have several flashlights that take 1 or 3 batteries.

Answer (score 2):

They don't. This is an assumption based on a very limited sample. I've seen just as many with odd numbers as I have with even.